# Retrieve element from nested JSON string

Tags: json, go

This is the Go code that I have:

```
func main(){

    s := string(`{"Id": "ABC123",
                  "Name": "Hello", 
                  "RelatedItems":[
                         {"RId":"TEST123","RName":"TEST1","RChildren":"Ch1"},
                         {"RId":"TEST234","RName":"TEST2","RChildren":"Ch2"}]
                  }`)

    var result map[string]interface{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &result)
    fmt.Println("Id:", result["Id"])
    Rlist := result["RelatedItems"].([]map[string]interface{})

    for key, pist := range pist {
        fmt.Println("Key: ", key)
        fmt.Println("RID:", pist["RId"])
    }

}
```

The struct is down below

```
type Model struct {
    Id   string `json:"Id"`
    Name string `json:"ModelName"`
    RelatedItems []RelatedItems `json:"RelatedItems"`
}

type RelatedItems struct {
    RId       string `json:"PCId"`
    RName     string `json:"PCName"`
    RChildren string `json:"string"`
}
```

How would I get an output that would let me choose a particular field from the above?
eg:

### Output

Id: ABC123
key:0
RID:TEST123
key:1
RID:TEST234

I am seeing this error

> panic: interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not []map[string]interface {}

Comment: Don't ignore errors!

Comment: The code you've included in your question a) doesn't compile, b) doesn't create that error. If I correct your code and [run it](https://play.golang.org/p/2B0D4DaftcD), I get a different error message.

Comment: @seesharper: There are many reasons a question can be off-topic, and still be about programming.

Comment: @seesharper In this case, I voted to close the question as off-topic, because it doesn't contain the information necessary to answer the question. The code doesn't compile, and the code doesn't produce the output claimed. There's literally no way of knowing what the OP needs to solve their situation without an update from the OP.

Comment: To be fair he hasn't claimed the output is what is happening, he states it's an example of what he is after. Think you may have misread the post due to the formatting (or could be I'm misreading it), but the content there does provide enough detail to me. It's got desired output, current error, and current code attempted.

Comment: My guess is this is roughly what you are after https://play.golang.org/p/mQCfyxFMrU7 - don't have time to put a proper answer together, but essentially make sure you are using the structs you created to decode to, and access them via `.` not via an index.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to comment. I am new and learning so I thought I could reach out for help and I was not able to find a definitive solution. I didn't claim to have an output and that was my desired output. Also it was my first question, I apologize for the formatting, in future if I ask any question I will format it better.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the posted content,
I'm clear that you are facing issues retrieving data from the nested JSON string.

I've taken your piece of code and tried to compile and reproduce the issue.
After observing, I have a few suggestions based on the way the code has been written.

1. When the datatype present in the `s` is known to be similar to the type `Model`, the `result` could have been declared as `type Model`.
   That results in `var result Model` instead of `map[string]interface{}`.
2. When the data that's gonna be decoded from the `interface{}` is not known, the usage of `switch` would come into rescue without crashing the code.
   Something similar to:

   `switch dataType := result["RelatedItems"].(type){
    case interface{}:
           // Handle interface{}
    case []map[string]interface{}:
           // Handle []map[string]interface{}
    default:
           fmt.Println("Unexpected-Datatype", dataType)
           // Handle Accordingly`
3. When we try to Unmarshal, we make sure to look into the `json tags` that are provided for the fields of a structure. If the data encoded is not having the tags we provided, the data will not be decoded accordingly.
   Hence, the result of decoding the data from `s` into `result` would result in `{ABC123  [{  } {  }]}` as the tags of the fields `Name`, `RId`, `RName`, `RChildren` are given as `ModelName`, `PCId`, `PCName`, `string` respectively.

By the above suggestions and refining the tags given, the piece of code would be as following which would definitely retrieve data from nested JSON structures.

```
s := string(`{"Id": "ABC123",
              "Name": "Hello",
              "RelatedItems":[
                     {"RId":"TEST123","RName":"TEST1","RChildren":"Ch1"},
                     {"RId":"TEST234","RName":"TEST2","RChildren":"Ch2"}]
              }`)

    var result Model
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &result)
    fmt.Println(result)

type Model struct {
        Id           string         `json:"Id"`
        Name         string         `json:"Name"`
        RelatedItems []RelatedItems `json:"RelatedItems"`
}

type RelatedItems struct {
        RId       string `json:"RId"`
        RName     string `json:"RName"`
        RChildren string `json:"RChildren"`
}
```

This results in the output: `{ABC123 Hello [{TEST123 TEST1 Ch1} {TEST234 TEST2 Ch2}]}`

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to help me out :)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you unmarshal to a map anyway and go through type checks?

```
type Model struct {
    Id   string `json:"Id"`
    Name string `json:"ModelName"`
    RelatedItems []RelatedItems `json:"RelatedItems"`
}

type RelatedItems struct {
    RId       string `json:"PCId"`
    RName     string `json:"PCName"`
    RChildren string `json:"string"`
}

s := `{"Id": "ABC123",
          "Name": "Hello",
          "RelatedItems":[
                 {"RId":"TEST123","RName":"TEST1","RChildren":"Ch1"},
                 {"RId":"TEST234","RName":"TEST2","RChildren":"Ch2"}]
    }`
var result Model
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &result); err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err.Error())
}

fmt.Println("Id: ", result.Id)
for index, ri := range result.RelatedItems {
    fmt.Printf("Key: %d\n", index)
    fmt.Printf("RID: %s\n", ri.RId)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. Also its result.Id, I am sure it was a typo but just adding it here for clarification.